# Dynamic DOB Year selection in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am using django 1.7.7.  I want to make a year selection dropdown using for loop.

```
  <option value="0">Year</option>
   {% for year in 2018|getxrange:1893 %}
   if year < 10 %}
    <option value="0{{year}}">0{{year}}</option>
   {% else %}
    <option value="{{year}}">{{year}}</option>
{% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

- Instead of 2018 I want a dynamic year.
- My Try: {% with now "Y" as year %} {%endwith%}
- Its not working. please suggest better way to achieve this.

Comment: Use the context from the view.

Comment: @Sayse only that is the way ?

Comment: There are other ways but that is the correct way